# How can I find the elements generating a group in a special way?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, products

Suppose, a finite permutation group G is given. I want to find the minimal set $x_1,...,x_n$ such that every element of $G$ can be uniquely written in
the form $$x_1^{j_1}...x_n^{j_n}$$ with $0\le j_i\le l_i$ for $i=1,...,n$.

This requirement is stronger than demanding a generating set because the product could be $x^2 y^3 x^2$, for example, which is not allowed in the restricted version. It is clear that the product of the orders of the $x_i$ must be at least the order of the group. It is also clear that $l_i$ must be smaller than the order of the element $x_i$.

Example : For the permutations $x=(1347)(2568)$ and $y=(1246)(3875)$,
          the set $[e,x,x^2,x^3,y,xy,x^2y,x^3y]$ forms the quaternion
          group $Q_8$.

> Does a set with the required property exist for every finite permutation group $G$ ?
>
> How can I find the smallest possible set and the exponents ? (The example shows that the limit for the exponent for some element need not be equal to the order of the element)

GAP allows to check whether a given  set forms the required group, but the brute-force-method will soon become infeasible.

Comment: The fact that $G$ is a permutation group rather than just a fintie group  seems irrelevant to the question. I would be surprised if such $x_i$ exist for every finite group $G$ but, as you say, it might be hard to prove that they do not. Is there any particular motivation for this problem?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think it is a good way to comprehend the structure of a group this way.

Comment: Tha's true for solvable groups, where you can choose $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ as polycyclic generators, but I doubt whether it works for every finite group.

Comment: Can I find out the polycyclic generators doing the job for a solvable finite group in GAP ?

Comment: Try IsomorphismPcGroup( G )